# Clear Hard Flat Plastic Surfaces Without Glass effect

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

Let me start off with saying, I am new to this.

I downloaded a model to play around with, as I know I am not good enough to make this item myself just yet (a jewel case) but I wanted to learn how to make materials. This one is giving me a lot of pain.

The geometry looks like so:
[image: Jewel Case - wire Frame Mesh]

My Goal is to get it as realistic as I can, and the preview seemed to have it looking pretty good, so I believe the mesh to be ok, but I assume I am making dumb mistakes.

My goal is to make it look like any normal jewel case

https://www.google.com/search?q=jewel+case&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS753US753&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5hfil3N7fAhUHy1kKHeXYC2AQ_AUIDigB&biw=1062&bih=967#imgrc=mKnE1-NPcqzMnM:

note the hard edges, here is what my render ends up looking like, no matter what I do....
[image]

Notice how it has more of a glass look and less of a hard plastic look, and it also seems to "lose" geometry, so it looks as though it has melted.

I just need a simple example of a flat plane with some extra geomotry added to it and a short explanation of how to do the effect, I have been trying for days and I am not even close (I have found quite a few examples, but nothing seems to work as I expect)

I would venture to guess I am missing something important.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what your material nodes currently look like?

Comment: Unfortunately I have been playing around with it an messed it up even more. The following is what I tried: https://blenderartists.org/t/rendering-a-transparent-plastic-box-in-blender-cycles/583147/6 Although, along with my own modifications. Although I didn't know what the "Glass Absorption" node was. I can post my current node, but right now it looks like a mirror.